# Is it possible to download all the files from a parent directory without manually clicking on each link?

Tags: linux, download, centos

Is it possible to download all the files in a parent directory?

I'm trying to download all the files here:

http://linux.mirrors.es.net/centos/5.6/isos/i386/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download how? You can use a browser extension like Firefox's [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) to grab all links on a page, though it's more optimized for media types by default (you can specify your own file masks, though).

Comment: Hi Marc, Can you please give me a play-by-play, I have DownThemAll but I'm unable to figure out how to dl all the files in the directory

Comment: Nevermind, you have to right click the page inside the directory

Comment: dTa can only download what's linked to from the current page (not _anything in the directory_). Though of course, in your example, with mod_autoindex enabled on that site, that isn't an issue, because all the files _are_ linked to. It's as easy as clicking anywhere and selecting "dTa 1-click".

Answer (score 1):

You can use wget with the recursive option. There are also many shareware apps that provide GUIs for sucking down the contents of a website.